# Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value

Tags: java, c#, json, date, restsharp

I'm using `REST SHARP` and creating data using c# code
`my service is of Java service.`

and i'm getting follwing convertion error
when I pass `CreatedDate = DateTime.Now`

Json

```
{"id":123,"createdDate":"2015-08-06T12:18:32.8405195+05:30"}
```

C# RestSharp code

```
  Customer cust = new Customer()
  cust.id=123;
  cust.createdDate = DateTime.Now;

  string jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust , new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

  var restClient = new RestClient("http://myurl/");    
  var restRequest = new RestRequest("rest/", Method.POST);    
  restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
  restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", jsonObject, ParameterType.RequestBody);
  restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");    
  // execute the request
  RestSharp.IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

> Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from
>   String value '2015-08-06T12:13:01.8564244+05:30': not a valid
>   representation (error: Failed to parse Date value
>   '2015-08-06T12:13:01.8564244+05:30': Can not parse date
>   \"2015-08-06T12:13:01.8564244+05:30\": not compatible with any of
>   standard forms (\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ\",
>   \"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'\", \"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz\",
>   \"yyyy-MM-dd\"))\n at [Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@19198464; line: 1,
>   column: 69]

Comment: Post your Json string

Comment: You seem to be having `7` digit millisecond field. I guess that's the problem.

Comment: Updated json data string

Comment: Try to pass simple in `string value` not in `DateTime value`

Comment: but in c# you can directly take it as `DateTime.Now` instead of conversion. there must be some code to convert internally while passing data using REST for DateTime variable?

Comment: What's in your `myclassobj` ?

Comment: simple model class like customer, updated as per customer example

Comment: `createdDate` declare as DateTime in your model class ? Try to pass UTC time in `createdDate`